# Clustering Connected Squares in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, grouping, mesh, hierarchical-clustering

Assume there is a mesh which is colored in the specific pattern:
[image]

As you can see, these 62 red squares are connected together in three different groups(Clusters). You might like to download the data from the following link.

[Click here for downloading mesh coordinates (XX, YY, ZZ) and its colours(C)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95465395/data.mat)

Then, you can generate the mesh below with this code:

```
load('data.mat');
figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]); % Opening big figure
axis equal; axis off;
SURF = surf( XX , YY , ZZ, C);
```

Now, I am looking for a code which can segment these three clusters.

Please bear in mind that you should consider those squares as a one group which have maximum one square gap distance in any direction. It means, in this particular case, we have three clusters of 11 , 13 and 38 squares.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Use `regionprops`. It will use 8-way connected regions, so if you were to input that mask it would return 3 regions. You can also specify properties you want (like `'Area'`, `'BoundingBox'`, `'Centroid'`, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [connected component labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling).

In Matlab, assuming your matrix contains only 0 and 1 (or you can make it so), you would use [bwlabel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html).

```
L = bwlabel(data, 8)
```

Now `L` will be a matrix the same size as `data` with labels `1, 2, 3...` in place of the 1's.

The `8` as the second parameter denotes the connectivity of the components. `4-connected` would mean that one square is connected to the other only if it is to the left, right, above or below the square. `8-connected` means that squares are also connected if they are adjacent diagonally, as in the bottom-right of your sample. `8` is the default, and you can leave it out, but you should be aware of the distinction in case you need it to behave differently in the future.